# How to calculate percent tree cover in a 1ac moving analysis window in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, analysis, arcgis

In the attached Matlab script, random locations are generated and assigned a value of 1-12.  Let's assume that each location >= 1 (i.e. value in the array) is a tree location and every value is a tree canopy radius.  I am interested in calculating percent canopy area in a 1 ac (e.g. 63.614 x 63.614) moving analysis window.  Let's also assume one pixel in the resulting image is equal to 1m.  In ArcGIS, I would use [Focal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000qs000000) to make this type of calculation.  For all the real programmers out there: How should I make this type of calculation using Matlab?

```
% Generate a totally black image to start with.
m = zeros(300, 400, 'uint8');

% Generate 1000 random "tree" locations.
numRandom = 1000;
linearIndices = randi(numel(m), 1, numRandom);

% Assign a radius value of 1-12 for each tree
m(linearIndices) = randi(12, [numel(linearIndices) 1]);

% Display it.  
image(m);
colormap(gray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how you want to calculate the percent area (not sure what 1ac means), but one way would be through using [nlfilter](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html). For example,

```
percentAreaImage = nlfilter(double(m), [63 63], @myfun);
```

where:

```
function pArea = myfun(block)
    % block is 63 x 63 pixles.
    sumRadii = sum(block(:)); % sum of canopy radii
    blockArea = size(block, 1)*size(block, 2);
    pArea = sumRadii / blockArea;
```

The code obviously may need some amendment, regarding the block size and the calculation of percent area (`pArea`). The `blockArea` is constant, so off course, it could be declared once, outside the `myfun` to improve performance. I left it as it is for clarity though.

Comment: Great, thanks @Marcin.  An "ac" is an acre, which translates to 4046 m^2 or [63.614 63.614].  I cannot seem to make this work with the sample data.  I keep getting the following error:  "Function definitions are not permitted in this context."  Any ideas how I can coerce these lines to work with the sample data?